# JPEG in a Word 2010 web page?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I post a JPEG file in a Word 2010 web page?

Comment: Just paste the pictur in your word page, then upload the picture on your hoster. You may edit your page with HTML code to have it properly shown.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to paste the picture in your Word Page. Then, upload the picture (And the page) on your web hoster. You may need to edit your page with HTML code to have it properly shown.